# Non trivial algebraic places

Tags: abstract-algebra

Zariski and Samuel II states if a field K over k has positive trans. degree an algebraic place of K/k exists. (Ch. VI, The 5, corr. 2). Could someone supply a non trivial example of such a place? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{P}(f(x))=f(0)$$ is an rational place on $k(x)$.